# closed MySQL connection in Rake task

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem similar to the one described in [Resque is returning Mysql2::Error: closed MySQL connection: SHOW FIELDS FROM `users`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543007/resque-is-returning-mysql2error-closed-mysql-connection-show-fields-from-us).

In my case, I see it during a long-running Rake task (3+ hours).  Basically the task runs along importing data from csvs, then suddenly starts spitting "closed MySQL connection" errors.  This only happens in our staging env with a remote MySql, can't repro locally.

So my question is, why can the Rails app (using the same connection properties) run for days without issue, but my data import task bombs after a few hours?

Answer (score 1):

Your connections are timing out. This happens all the time on long running rake tasks with the mysql driver. Try setting the reconnect flag in your database.yml

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html#reconnecting-mysql-connections

Basically just add:

```
reconnect: true
```

I am surprised this is not documented more as I run into it all the time. If that doesnt work, try explicitly calling

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionHandler#verify_active_connections!
```